# AWS Athena select query to fetch error code from status column

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

AWS Athena trying to run a select query as below to fetch error code from the status column, but getting the below error

The query which I am trying:

```
select * from s3_accesslog where status = '404'
```

Error: SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:78: '=' cannot be applied to integer, varchar(3)

```
select * from s3_accesslog where status like '%404%'
```

Error: SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:71: Left side of LIKE expression must evaluate to a varchar (actual: integer)

Comment: you may try to cast it to string `CAST(status AS VARCHAR)` or `CAST(status AS STRING)`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your status codes are stored in the table as integers, if you remove the quotes the query should work.

So try:

`select * from s3_accesslog where status = 404`